# Triple integral bounded by R

Tags: integration

I have to evaluate
$$\iiint\limits_R{4y^2ze^{xy}dxdydz}$$
where $R$ is the region bounded by
$$x=0,\; y=1,\; y=x,\; z=0,\; z=1.$$

I did $y=x{,}\space x=0{,}\space y=1 \Rightarrow \int_{0}^1\int_{x}^1\int_{0}^y{4y^2ze^{xy}dxdydz}$

is this correct? if it's not please tell me what's wrong, and give hint.
thank u all

Comment: how R is empty? i wrote R: x=0, y=1, y=x, z= 0, z=1

Comment: Exactly: which points $(x,y)$ fulfill $x=0$, $y=1$ and $x=y$ at the same time?

Comment: A region of the plane / a region of the space is usually given by inequalities, not equalities.

Comment: Yeah that exactly what confuses me, the question was written just like this.

Comment: http://imgur.com/wDiOdDN that is the question, i was thinking that i should draw the graph to see the limits

Comment: And exactly as I thought, the crucial **bounded by** part is missing in your question.

Comment: yeah you're right, but i just wrote it in the title i should've mentioned it in the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the actual problem is to evaluate
$$ I= \iiint_{R} 4y^2 z e^{xy}\,dx\,dy\,dz $$
where $R=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: 0\leq x,z\leq 1,0\leq x \leq y\}$. This problem instantly boils down to evaluate an integral over a triangle region:
$$ I = 2\iint_{T} y^2 e^{xy}\,dx\,dy $$
where $T=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\}$. So we have:
$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}y^2 e^{xy}\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{1}2y\left(e^{y^2}-1\right)\,dy =\left[e^{y^2}-y^2\right]_{0}^{1}=\color{red}{e-2}. $$

Comment: Thank you so much jack, if you don't mind can please explain to me how did you go from $I= \iiint_{R} 4y^2 z e^{xy}\,dx\,dy\,dz$ to $I = 2\iint_{T} y^2 e^{xy}\,dx\,dy$

Comment: did u used Fubini's theorem to change order then integrate wrt z first? that's it?

Comment: @corfto: yep, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Project the region into the $xy$ plane, this is what you should see
[image]

the limits are then

$$
\int_R{\rm d}V (\cdot) = \int_0^1{\rm d}z\int_0^1{\rm d}x\int_x^1{\rm d}y (\cdot)
$$

Comment: Thank you, that what i was doing, but how did u change the order dx and dy?

Comment: @corfto: are you aware of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @corfto Intuitively speaking if you integrate first wrt $x$, then the integral wrt $y$ cannot  bring back around $x$, because the result will end up depending on this variable

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio no but thanks to u i'm reading about it now.

Comment: @caverac Thank you so much, now i understand, Fubini's theorem was what i needed to know.